# Can't SSH through screen

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I have set up hosts.allow on the remote Arch Linux server as follows:

```
sshd: ALL: ALLOW
```

while hosts.deny is set to:

```
ALL: ALL
```

I have no problems using SSH through Cygwin (with a Corkscrew tunnel through a proxy server). When I open screen in Cygwin and try to SSH however, I receive the following error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

The verbose output is as follows:

```
$ ssh -v [username]@[remote server]
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Applying options for [remote server]
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec /usr/bin/corkscrew [proxy server] 80 [remote server] 443 ~/.corkscrew-auth
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 152811
No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/[username]/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[username]/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[username]/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/[username]/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I've already tried removing the SSH keys from both the client and the server and I get the same error.

Like I said before, SSH works fine when I'm not using screen. I can't work out why the SSH connection is being dropped when it is run through screen though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure where the problem was (i.e. with OpenSSH, Corkscrew, or somewhere else), however it has disappeared after updating Cygwin to the latest version of all packages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your `hosts.allow` syntax is valid. Try:

```
sshd: ALL
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that layout and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like corkscrew can't find configuration file `~/.corkscrew-auth` or `/usr/bin/corkscrew` binary itself.

According to corkscrew manual page file `~/.corkscrew-auth` should contain account info: `username:password`

Comment: Hi - thanks for your reply but Corkscrew is working fine (with the config located at ~/.corkscrew-auth), so the problem lies elsewhere.